# Change row values with certain condition, using row values from json dataset Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataset

I have this dataset.

```
{
    "date": "2018-01-01", 
    "body": "some txt", 
    "id": 111, 
    "sentiment": null
}, 
{
    "date": "2018-01-02", 
    "body": "some txt", 
    "id": 112, 
    "sentiment": {
        "basic": "Bearish"
    }
}
```

I want to read this with pandas, and change the column sentiment foreach rows differents from null.

When I do this:

```
pd.read_json(path)
```

this is the result that I get:

```
body           ...    sentiment
0                      None
1                      {u'basic': u'Bullish'}
```

I don't want to have `{u'basic': u'Bullish'}` but only the value of basic. 
So to find the correct rows I use

```
df.loc[self.df['sentiment'].isnull() != True, 'sentiment'] = (?)
```

and it work, but I don't know what I have to put instead of (?)

I've tried this but doens't work

```
df.loc[self.df['sentiment'].isnull() != True, 'sentiment'] = df['sentiment']['basic]
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

```
mask = df['sentiment'].notnull()
df.loc[mask, 'sentiment'] = df.loc[mask, 'sentiment'].apply(lambda x: x['basic'])
```

Comment: It works. Thanks. This answer will be mark as correct.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
df = pd.read_json(path)  # creates the dataframe with dict objects in sentiment column 
pd.concat([df.drop(['sentiment'], axis=1), df['sentiment'].apply(pd.Series)], axis=1)  # create new columns for each sentiment type
```

So for example, if your json is :

```
[{
    "date": "2018-01-01", 
    "body": "some txt", 
    "id": 111, 
    "sentiment": null
}, 
{
    "date": "2018-01-02", 
    "body": "some txt", 
    "id": 112, 
    "sentiment": {
        "basic": "Bearish"
    }
},
{
    "date": "2018-01-03", 
    "body": "some other txt", 
    "id": 113, 
    "sentiment": {
        "basic" : "Bullish",
        "non_basic" : "Bearish"
    }
}]
```

df after line 1:

```
             body       date   id                                     sentiment
0        some txt 2018-01-01  111                                          None
1        some txt 2018-01-02  112                          {'basic': 'Bearish'}
2  some other txt 2018-01-03  113  {'basic': 'Bullish', 'non_basic': 'Bearish'}
```

df after line 2:

```
             body       date   id    basic non_basic
0        some txt 2018-01-01  111      NaN       NaN
1        some txt 2018-01-02  112  Bearish       NaN
2  some other txt 2018-01-03  113  Bullish   Bearish
```

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

#### [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) + [`pop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) + [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html)

Here's an extendible solution which avoids row-wise `apply` and converts an arbitrary number of keys to series:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'body': [0, 1],
                   'sentiment': [None, {u'basic': u'Bullish'}]})

df['sentiment'] = df['sentiment'].fillna(pd.Series([{}]*len(df.index), index=df.index))

df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(df.pop('sentiment').values.tolist()))

print(df)

   body    basic
0     0      NaN
1     1  Bullish
```